# Speed for \animate in beamer

Tags: beamer, animate

The following example is taken from
The beamer class
User Guide for version 3.41. by Till Tantau, Joseph Wright, Vedran Miletić
at http://tug.ctan.org/
(except that I inserted the various `\pause`)

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A Five Slide Animation}
\animate<2-4>
The first slide is shown normally. 
\pause
When the second slide is shown
(presumably after pressing a forward key), 
\pause
the second, third, and
fourth slides ‘‘flash by.’’ 
\pause
At the end, the content of the fifth
slide is shown.
... code for creating an animation with five slides ...
\end{frame}
```

This does almost exactly what I want except for one thing: the speed of the animation when slides 2-4 are shown in rapid succession. I would like to be able to slow that down, but I cannot figure out how.

Comment: Does the provided answer solve the problem? If yes, then consider accepting it.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `\transduration<⟨overlay specification⟩>{⟨number of seconds⟩}` instead, you can specify the time in seconds.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\transduration<2-4>{1}
The first slide is shown normally. 
\pause
When the second slide is shown
(presumably after pressing a forward key), 
\pause
the second, third, and
fourth slides ‘‘flash by.’’ 
\pause
At the end, the content of the fifth
slide is shown.
... code for creating an animation with five slides ...
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```